# Program not responding from SearchListResponse

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to gather data of YouTube videos using a Winforms app. When I call `YTSearch()` method as seen below, The program stops responding when it gets to

```
var slResponse = await slRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

The request is started, but does not stop, and is neither finished, nor triggering the catch on a try catch. I have managed to get the exact same thing working using a Discord bot, using Discord.NET. In the output is

> Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in Google.Apis.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in mscorlib.dll`

**Libraries:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

**Method:**

```
public async Task<List<Video>> YTSearch(string query)
{
    string ytAPI = APIKEY; // Ommitted
    var ytService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = ytAPI,
        ApplicationName = "YouTubeDownloader"
    });
    var slRequest = ytService.Search.List("snipper");
    slRequest.Q = query;
    slRequest.MaxResults = 10;
    var slResponse = await slRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    List<Video> vidList = new List<Video>();
    return vidList;
}
```

**Call:**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Video> vidList = YTSearch(txtSearch.Text).Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I'm fairly sure you need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. So in your `YTSearch` method you need to use the line:

```
var slResponse = await slRequest.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is required because you are blocking for the result in the button handler, by using `.Result`.

[This MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/) is a little old, but explains the problem.

Comment: I'll try it now

Answer (score 0):

First off you have a small typo you should fix that is unrelated to your error.   The first parameter is part valid values are

1. contentDetails: 2
2. id: 0
3. snippet: 2

You have snipper

It isn't clear that this is the issue as the error you are getting isn't related to the API.

The issue sounds more like a problem with the dll.  I would try to reimport the nuget package make sure you are using.net 4.5 in your project

Comment: I'm not on my PC right now, but I think that actually might be the error. I'll check it now

Comment: Well, the snipper thing isn't the error, and I am using .NET 4.6.1. I have reimported the nuget package yet still receiving the error.

Comment: I will boot up my pc latter today and test it